# Bibliography with utf8x and acm style

Tags: bibliographies, input-encodings, acm

I'm writing an internship report in french. I'm using MikTeX and pdfLaTeX with TeXstudio

I want to make my bibliography with the acm style but I discovered that I can't use biblatex with `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` whereas I need that package in order to use special characters.

I don't care if I have to use something else than BibLaTeX, I just need a simple way of editing my bibliography with the utf8x package and the acm style.

Using the default bibliography with the `\bibliography{mybibliography}` at the end did work but changing the style with `\bibliographystyle{acm}` didn't produce any changes...

Is there a simple way to do it ?

Comment: You probably don't need `utf8x` - one can almost always use `[utf8]` and add missing declarations.  Beside this your question is really unclear, and you should make a minimal example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Ok thank you I'll try finding a workaround so I can use utf8, I can't post a MWE as I don't have all my files on this work computer, I'll try later when I'll be at home.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I found the solution, I had to delete the old .bbl file and use utf8 instead of utf8x as suggested and it worked fine.